# What is the correct way to inject services in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just learning AngularJS and I'm finding many different ways to do the same thing and I'm really wondering which is better and why to choose one option over the other.

I've seen controllers created both ways:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customersService) {});
```

and

```
app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', 'customersService', function ($scope, customersService) {}]);
```

Obviously the second way is more typing, but is there a benefit to using that way over the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both will work in general, but only the second syntax will work once the code is minified. Most JavaScript minifiers will rename argument identifiers, so your code may look something like this:

```
a.controller('CustomersController',function(b,c){});
```

If that happens, Angular can no longer determine which services need to be injected. However, if you use the array syntax you will get minified code that looks something like this:

```
a.controller('CustomersController',['$scope','customersService',function(b,c){}]);
```

In this case, the final element of the array is used as the controller function, and all previous elements are strings representing the names of services. That list is effectively applied to the controller function, with each service identified by an arbitrary identifier chosen by the minifier.

Comment: A question here - after writing the controller just like the second option, is it needed to also write the code `CustomersController.$inject = ['$scope']` or is this only required with the first option?

Answer (score 1):

Either one is fine, the second one is suggested if you plan on minifying your code as the first one will become minified to something like:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function (a, b) {});
```

Which won't work because of how dependency injection works, but the second one will become:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', 'customersService', function (a, b) {}]);
```

Which angular knows internally to put $scope in for a and customersService in for b.

Answer (score 0):

Using second way lets you minify your code with variables. If you wouldn't do this:

```
['$scope', 'customersService', function ($scope, customersService) {}]
```

Then your variables could be minified which will break your application.